# REST API call not getting Data when apps is debugging on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode5

I am calling Rest API in my application by following way

```
-(NSArray*)parse_Data_From_URL:(NSString*)URL
{

    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:URL];

    // we'll receive raw data so we'll create an NSData Object with it
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

    // now we'll parse our data using NSJSONSerialization
    id myJSON = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];


    // typecast an array and list its contents

    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSArray new];
    jsonArray = (NSArray *)myJSON;

  //  NSLog(@"json floor plan imageTite --- %@",jsonArray);

    return jsonArray;

}
```

My code is working fine when I am running my apps on iPad simulator, but when I am running apps on **device** it **API response** getting null value & application is going to terminate .

Comment: 1) `NSArray *jsonArray = [NSArray new];` is unnecessary since you assign `myJSON` to it immediately after it. 2) Typecasting `myJSON` to `NSArray` doesn't automagically convert the object to an array (you might be getting a dictionary back for example). 3) Just set a breakpoint after the deserialisation and inspect the object and any errors.

Comment: Did you confirm your device has an internet connection?

Comment: Y my device have internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be ignoring the fact that there could be an error:

```
-(NSArray*)parse_Data_From_URL:(NSString*)URL
{

    NSURL *myURL = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:URL];

    // we'll receive raw data so we'll create an NSData Object with it
    NSData *myData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

    // now we'll parse our data using NSJSONSerialization
    NSError *err = nil;
    NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:myData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&err];

    if (err) {
        // do something about error
        NSLog("Error retrieving data: %@", err);
    }

    // this will be nil if there is an error.  May want to consider adding NSError ** to parse_Data_From_URL parameters
    return jsonArray;

}
```